# Windows 10 prints pink to an Okidata OKI-MPS2731m

Tags: windows-10, printer, compatibility

I'm in a small office setting with several computers accessing one printer: An Okidata OKI-MPS2731mc. Today, my printer suddenly decided blue = pink.

Obviously, I suspected the toner levels, but when I asked my colleague to print the same document, it came out perfect. It's happened enough times now that I know it's not a fluke.

I should note that I'm the only one in the office running Windows 10 (the rest are Windows 7). I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the printer, but no improvement.

I've read there is a way to install a printer in compatibility mode using "God Mode" settings. I've enabled "God Mode" but I don't know where this compatibility setting is.

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Inkjet-Printing/Printer-prints-wrong-colors-after-windows-10-update/m-p/5599254#M544392

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you link to that specific suggestion?  In the context of "god mode", it refers to a folder with a specific GUID, but that specifically has nothing to do with printers.

Comment: @ Ramhound - see my edit

Comment: I will be honest without knowing what the author of that comment did exactly, their comment does not make any sense, there is nothing special about any of the printer options within the "God Mode" folder.  **I believe the advice, about the god mode folder, is a lame duck personally.**

Comment: OK, any Ideas how to fix this wonky colour?

Comment: In case Windows updated the driver, in Properties of the printer, try to rollback the driver.

Comment: I managed to fix the printer issue by installing from the original disc, rather than though the windows prompts... only problem now is I can't scan!

Comment: OK, I got it!  Windows 10 assigns generic drivers which work for the scanner, but does a lousy job printing.  The answer is to have 2 installs -- 1 from the disc, one through the windows prompts.